# Regular Expression for Password - does not begin with, does not contain

Tags: regex, passwords, expression

I have a set of requirements for password comlpexity that I am part of the way through solving but am having trouble in some specific areas. The current expression I have is as follows:

```
^(?=(.*\d){2,4})(?=(.*[A-Z]))(?=(.*[a-z])).{8}$
```

This expression (as far as I am aware and have tested) will require an 8 character password that contains at least one upper case letter, a lower case letter and at least two numbers but no more than 4.

The remaining requirements I would like to implement are as follows:
- contain at least 3 different alphabetic characters
- not start with a number
- not contain special characters
- not begin with three identical characters (i.e. aaa, ccc).

I would greatly appreciate any help or guidance on these.

Comment: [Holy password complexity, Batman.](http://xkcd.com/936/)

Comment: If you're doing it as a "regex-exercise" that's fine, otherwise, the right thing to do is check all the requirements using a `validate()` method with distinct tests. It'll be easier to read and maintain in the future (in case you decide to change one to the requirements).

Comment: Also, the set of possible passwords given this massive list of restrictions is... somewhat on the small side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works.
*(Note - recommend you exclude whitespace as well)*

```
 # ^(?=.{8}$)(?!\d)(?=\PP*$)(?=(.)(?!\1\1))(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=(?:\D*\d){2,4}\D*$)(?=.*([a-zA-Z]).*(?!\2)([a-zA-Z]).*(?!\2|\3)[a-zA-Z]).*$

 ^                            # BOS
 (?= .{8} $ )                 # 8 characters total
 (?! \d )                     # Not start with digit
 (?= \PP* $ )                 # No Punct (special chars?)
 (?=                          # Not start 3 identical chars
      ( . )                   # (1)
      (?! \1 \1 )
 )
 (?= .* [A-Z] )               # At least 1 upper
 (?= .* [a-z] )               # At least 1 lower
 (?=                          # At least 2 digits, no more than 4
      (?: \D* \d ){2,4}
      \D* $ 
 )
 (?=                          # At least 3 different alpha chars
      .* 
      ( [a-zA-Z] )            # (2)
      .* 
      (?! \2 )
      ( [a-zA-Z] )            # (3)
      .* 
      (?! \2 | \3 )
      [a-zA-Z] 
 )
 .* 
 $                            # EOS
```

***Recommended*** - [RegexFormat4](http://www.regexformat.com) to read / maintain code.

Perl test case

```
if( '~5bC$=6c' =~ /^(?=.{8}$)(?!\d)(?=\PP*$)(?=(.)(?!\1\1))(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=(?:\D*\d){2,4}\D*$)(?=.*([a-zA-Z]).*(?!\2)([a-zA-Z]).*(?!\2|\3)[a-zA-Z]).*$/)
{
    print "Matched  $&\n";
}
```

Output >>

```
Matched  ~5bC$=6c
```

Comment: is \Pp meant to be \pP?

Comment: @user3153407 - Fixed, it should have been \PP, ie: NOT punctuation